# Python program seems to assign one variable to an array

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, scipy-optimize

In Python, I am studying a textbook example of optimization with **Lagrange multipliers**. The sample source code works correctly in finding out the mathematical minimums; however, I don't understand the system behaviour of statement `[x, y, λ]  = xyλ` in the below function:

```
def DL(xyλ):
    [x, y, λ] = xyλ # <-- What does this statement do?
    return np.array([
        dfdx(x, y) - λ * dgdx(x, y),
        dfdy(x, y) - λ * dgdy(x, y),
        - g(x, y)
    ])
```

I thought it didn't make sense to assign one single variable to an array of multiple elements. So, I am also wondering why the sample program doesn't break on that line.

Comment: Typically it would be written as `x, y, λ = xyλ`;  It's called `unpacking`.  As long as `xyλ` has 3 elements, each of those is assigned to the three variables.  i.e. `x = xyλ[0]`, etc.  In `optimize.root(DL, [x0, y0, l0])` the initial guess is a list of 3 values.  That determines the size of array that `root` passes to `DL`.

Comment: This isn't "assigning to an array", this is actually "iterable unpacking". Both `()` and `[]` can be used to *group* the unpacking target, but they are equivalent. E.g. you could do something liek `(x, (y, z)) = [1, (2, 3)]` or `[x, [y, z]] = [1, (2, 3)]` or `[x, (y, z)] = [1, (2, 3)]` and they are all equivalent

Comment: See a linked duplicate for an in-depth exploration of these constructs